# while loop is not waiting till the function execution

Tags: while-loop

I'm trying to loop the objects inside while loop but I'm unable to get the result.. Actually I was assuming that the value of counter is incrementing after executing the function inside while loop... but the value of counter is getting increase before the function execution... I'm not getting why this is happening...

here is my test.ts

```
export class HelloIonicPage {
_i: number = 0;
barcode(index, pickuplist) {
   BarcodeScanner.scan()
   .then((barcodeData) => {
      if (barcodeData.cancelled) {
        alert("User cancelled the action!");
        return false;
      }
      this.bartxt = barcodeData.text;
      if (this.bartxt != '') {
        this.authservice.testFunction(this.bartxt)
          .subscribe(data => {
            if (data !== '') {
              alert("Scanned successfully!");
              alert(this._i);                     //here the value of i should be 0, but it showing 2
              if (this._i == (this.totalorders - 1)) {
                 alert(this._i + " _index");
                 this.finalacceptvendor(index, pickuplist);
               } else {
                 alert(this._i + " _index");
                 this.vendorbarcode(index, pickuplist);
               }
            } else {
              this.vendorbarcode(index, pickuplist);
              alert( Wrong QR Code);
            }
          });
        }
      });
     }
vendorbarcode(index, pickuplist) {
    this.totalorders = 2;
    while (this._i < this.totalorders) {
      alert(this._i + "_index");           //here the value of i = 0
        this.barcode(index, pickuplist);
      this._i = this._i + 1;
    }
   }
  }
```

i'm stuck here from last two days... please help mke sort this issue

Comment: why cant you get the result?

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the function?  Having a counter stored at the member level seems the wrong approach. From what I gather, it looks like you have a list of items to scan, and then once it has been scanned, it doesn't need  to be scanned again.  I would just have the items removed from the list instead of trying to maintain a counter.  Should be much simpler.

Comment: What you are trying to do isn't possible if you don't make vendorbarcode an async function. a while loop will not wait on an asynchronous action before it continues without async/await.

Comment: the purpose of the function is .. assume, I have two orders so i want to scan the order two times. But in the above function I'm calling the this.barcode(index, pickuplist); function inside vendorbarcode(index, pickuplist) function and after executing the barcode(index, pickuplist); function the counter must be increment. But in the above function the counter firstly initializes to _i = 0; after that it calls the function barcode(index, pickuplist); and its not waiting to complete the execution of function . the value of i increments before execution of function...

Comment: Hi kevin, how can i make vendorbarcode as async function ?

Comment: mdn async await

Comment: Could you please share some sort of code...?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: I have gone through this link.. but not getting how to make vendorbarcode(index, pickuplist) {} function to async function....

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by making the vendorbarcode(index, pickuplist) to asyn function as follow:

```
public vendorbarcode = function (index, pickuplist) {
    this.totalorders = this.pickuplist[index].Total_Orders;
    this.vendorid = this.pickuplist[index].VendorId;
    // async stuff, like fetching users from server, returning a response
    this.authservice.getorderidsFunction(this.vendorid)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.orderids = data[this._i].OrderId;
        while (this._i < data.length) {
          this.barcode(index, pickuplist)
            .then(function (response) {
            });
        }
      });
  }
```